# Express.Js having same param name but not passed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodes

So I have an issue with Express.Js currently. When I goto `/article/14` it returns with these as the parameter.

```
{ artId: '14' }
{ artId: 'img' }
```

However, I'm not sure where it gets the `img` part from or how the value is there twice. However, if I go to a different Id article it works fine.

This is the full code

```
app.get('/article/:artId', async function (req, res) {
    let artId = req.params.artId;
    getDiscordUserInfo(req, res, function(disData) {
        connection.query(`SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = ${artId}`, (err, artResults) => {
            if(artResults[0]) {
                connection.query(`SELECT * FROM articles WHERE deleted = 0 AND catId = ${artResults[0].catId}`, (err, catArtsResults) => {
                    connection.query(`SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = ${artResults[0].catId}`, (err, resultsCat) => {
                        res.render('article', {discordInfo: disData, siteInfo: config['siteInformation'], art: artResults[0], catArts: catArtsResults, cat: resultsCat[0], mdConvert: md});
                    });
                });
            } else {
                res.redirect('/'); 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

It also seems to still load the page and then crash because of `img`.

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be resolved. To make the articles I use a [markdown converter](https://github.com/FAXES/markdown-it-faxes) and the image I placed in the body of the page seems to be the cause. I didn't have the link yet so I used `img` as a placeholder in the code which made this the result;

[image: img]

Not sure how this in the body would be a cause but somehow was.

Answer (score 0):

aha,,,

```
app.get('/article/:artId')
```

:artId is dynamic params.
so if you have the same route maybe in your case

```
app.get('/article/:artId') // route 1
app.get('/article/img') // route 2
```

simple solution just add conditon before query to database

```
if(artId !== "img")
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you! I got it last night. Just me being silly lol